# Problem with webpack encore : error compilation less

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack, compilation, less, webpack-encore

I have a compilation problem with Bootstrap files (Webpack Encore) :

> Error evaluating function `percentage`: argument must be a number
> Error in /app/assets/less/variables.less (line 302, column 26)

Code : `@fluidGridColumnWidth:    percentage(@gridColumnWidth/@gridRowWidth);`

The problem arise from reading parentheses with the division

If : `@fluidGridColumnWidth:    percentage((@gridColumnWidth/@gridRowWidth));` -> It works

I can't use this solution because the solution with vendors of Symfony :

> @import "../../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";

I tried to use **StrictMath true or 'division'** -> doesn't work

```
    .enableLessLoader((options) => { return {lessOptions: { strictMath: true}}; })
```

Nota Bene : I have another project where I have the same code that works. So I fixed the versions to be identical to this project but it doesn't work either.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Alternative :

Remove StrictMath
-> solves the problem of parentheses

The problem with compil bootstrap file 4.3.1 on a `background:url` calculation :

```
Cannot read property 'denominator' of undefined
```

I used version 4.2.1 of the bootstrap file for these lines

> DONE  Compiled successfully